# Can't "Resolve conflict using 'theirs'"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN and I am working on a branch to patch a project. The first time I merged the branch into the trunk the project had some problems so I rolled back that merge (which deleted a couple folders in the process). I switched my working copy to the branch (which has the folders) and made a bunch of changes to try to fix the problems I had last release.

Now I have switched my local copy to the trunk again (which is missing those folders due to the roll back) to perform the merge but there were tree conflicts because the folders were deleted in the trunk as part of the rollback and I cannot choose to resolve the conflict by accepting the branch's version which has the folders because TortoiseSVN says **"Tree conflict can only be resolved to 'working' state;"** I have also tried switching back to the branch but I get the same problem: the folders are in conflict and I cannot resolve the conflict by taking the branch, only the working state.

Comment: Sounds like you got yourself into a nasty state. If the new folders are your only problem I would do a manual add (bring them from your branch to the trunk and commit). You'd lose the history, but your project would be "intact".

Comment: @AlG If you put that as an answer with an explanation of how to go about that, I would probably accept it as the answer. My research doesn't lead me to believe what I want is possible, but since my local copy is gone since I switched to trunk to attempt the merge, I don't know how to do what you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, I think your switching and attempted fixing has put you into an odd state that you're going to have to manually resolve.

1. Pull **both** your branch and the trunk to separate directories. You are not restricted (by SVN) to having only one locally.
2. Once you have both, pull the missing files/directories from your branch into the trunk.
3. Verify your build!
4. Then add the new files to the trunk and commit.

Comment: I ended up doing this, but there was one small hiccup. When I moved the contents from the directory tied to the branch into the directory tied to the trunk, and then went to commit, SVN thought that directory was now on the branch and tried to commit there. To solve this, I told SVN to unversion and ignore the contents of the directory tied to the branch and then copied it over to the directory tied to the trunk. Worked fine after that.